# Delete has_one through: association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, through: :jobs_user
  has_one :jobs_user, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and the model for the join_table looks like this:

```
class JobsUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The migration was:

```
create_join_table :jobs, :shops do |t|
  t.index :job_id
end
```

When I create a job and try to delete it fails :

```
j = Job.create(user: User.last)
j.destroy!
  Job Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs"  ORDER BY "jobs"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  JobsShop Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "jobs_shops".* FROM "jobs_shops" WHERE "jobs_shops"."job_id" = 21365 LIMIT 1  [["job_id", 21365]]
  SQL (0.7ms)  DELETE FROM "jobs_shops" WHERE "jobs_shops"."" = NULL  [[nil, nil]]
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "jobs_shops" WHERE "jobs_shops"."" = NULL
                                                      ^
: DELETE FROM "jobs_shops" WHERE "jobs_shops"."" = NULL
```

It seems I failed somewhere and it cannot find the column to destroy.

Comment: Are you shure about ` has_one :through` association? ` has_many :through` seems to be more appropriate here

Comment: @MikhailKatrin but I want my job to be attached to only one shop not few.

Comment: Look [has_one :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association) association. Is it differ from what you want?

Comment: hi, usually if you do `j.errors.full_messages` you get a more clear explanation of why it is failing .

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I think the error is clear enough no?

Comment: @MikhailKatrin Nope this is what I want even if I'm using a join table to do it

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25347#issuecomment-300067025

> > Active Record doesn't have built in support for composite primary keys
>
> That means you can't manipulate a model whose corresponding table doesn't have a single-column primary key defined. That includes doing so through an association that uses said model.

So in my case, choosing `create_join_table` was not the right choice. Instead create a normal table.

```
create_table :users_jobs do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :job_id
  # t.index :job_id
end
```